# How to convert a unix timestamp field in views

Tags: 7, entities, views

I'm keeping a Unix timestamp in a text field.  In Views, I want to convert it to a readable date.  This is a commerce view, and the field is a custom field of an order.

Can I use hook_field_formatter_view() to use as my own formatter?  Something like:

```
function mymod_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {

    if ($entity_type == 'commerce_order') {
          // figure out field type and instance
    }
```

}

If that is a way to do it, I want to look at the params through Devel, so what can I return until I'm ready to operate on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to change the output of your field..

> This hook is called right before the render process. The query has
>   been executed, and the pre_render() phase has already happened for
>   handlers, so all data should be available.
>
> Adding output to the view can be accomplished by placing text on
>   $view->attachment_before and $view->attachment_after. Altering the
>   content can be achieved by editing the items of $view->result.

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

   if ($view->name=='viewyouarelookingfor') {

      // do whatever you want

   }

 }
```